# In need of Java vector operation explanation

Tags: java, vector, casting

I am a Java beginner attempting to translate a java program to another language and would very much appreciate an explanation of the actions being performed by the last line of the following code. Please be as detailed as you can.  Any insight is extremely valued.

```
class vector1 {
Vector first = new Vector();
}

public name {
int a = 1;
Vector last = new Vector();
num1 = ((vector1)last.elementAt(a)).first.size();
}
```

Comment: this is not valid java code

Comment: This code won't  compile.

Comment: vector first = new Vector(); -- what's vector? Shoud be Vector

Comment: public name -- what is that? is it a method? what's the return type?

Comment: int a = 1 -- where's the ; ?

Comment: Vector last = new Vector() -- where's the ; ?

Comment: num1 = ((vector1)last.elementAt(a)).first.size(); -- where num is declared?

Comment: @weston too many assumptions to make a such small snippet compile :-)

Comment: @Leo Yeah, clutching at straws!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here it goes

```
import java.util.Vector;

class vector1 { //classes should be capitalized

    Vector  first   = new Vector();

    public void name() { //methods must have a return type 
                         //(even if it's void) and must have input parameters between ()

        int a = 1; //java statements end with ;
        Vector last = new Vector(); //java statements end with ;        

//      int num1 = ((vector1) last.elementAt(a)).first.size();

        /*
         * this is the same as
         */     

        Object lastElement = last.elementAt(a); //this is the second element from "last" 
                                                //because the first element's index is 0 
                                                //Since "last" is empty, you'll get an error here

        vector1 v = (vector1)lastElement; //now you're forcing the compiler to assume that lastElement is a Vector
        Vector v2 = v.first;              //now you're getting vector's attribute "first", which is another Vector
        int num1 = v2.size();             //now you're calling the method size() on v.first to get the vector number of elements
    }
}
```

Comment: "*and must have input parameters between ()*" This reads a little misleadingly, as though you think there must always be something between the parentheses.

Comment: Thank you so much. If I may, in the "Vector v2 = v.first;" statement, what is the purpose of obtaining vector's attribute "first"? Is it to allow v2 to be treated as a vector?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can just about be answered, despite the horrendously un-compilable code...

The last line retrieves the `a`th (1st) element of the `last` vector, casts it to a `vector1` type and then retrieves the `first` field and queries it for its size.*

An easier to understand re-write might be:

```
vector1 v = (vector1) last.elementAt(a);
num1 = v.first.size();
```

Since the code [isn't using generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html), we don't know what type of object is in the vector. This code uses a cast to tell the compiler that you're sure the object is a `vector1` type. This allows you to access the fields of that class.

*<sub>Of course, this will fail miserably since nothing has been put into the vector in the first place.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your response! This is making much more sense now. I have one final question and I believe I will fully understand what's going on. What do you mean by "first field" and what is the significance of retrieving the size of "first"?

Comment: How will the value of num1 be affected?

Comment: @user49193 `num1` will be assigned the current value of `v.first.size()`. It's hard to provide more specific advice in your case, since your code example doesn't compile.